# Grep first charcter from the string

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, grep

```
10:30:01
10:35:01
```

There is a time in a format, where i want to grep:

- Case1: 1 from 10
- Case2: 3 from 30
  Output as

```
1
3
0
```

**10-17-22** date in a format where i want to grep **10**, **17**, **22**, seperately.

Output as:

```
10 
17
22
```

Is this possible using grep or awk?

Comment: Your question is unclear. First, the subject is "grep first charachter from a string", but that's not at all what you're asking. Secindly, what happens if your string has multiple time or date instances? For instance, you begin your question with two different times. Thirdly, in the first case, it seems you also want rhe first digit from the seconds, but you din't mentiin that. And last thing, you're using the term `grep` wrongly. You don't necessarily need this command to achieve your goal.

Comment: Important for the selction of tools: Where does the input come from: A File? A pipe (command output)? A variable? And where do you need the output, file, stdout or variable?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `grep`. `grep` is used to extract _lines from text_.

Answer (score 1):

A clarification in the question would help,
but here is something that could be of use :

Print specific chars (first, 4th and 7th) with awk :

```
$ echo "10:30:01" | awk '{print substr($1,1,1)"\n"substr($1,4,1)"\n"substr($1,7,1)}'
1
3
0
$
```

Replace '-' by newlines with tr :

```
$ echo 10-17-22 | tr '-' '\n'
10
17
22
$
```

Grep only two consecutive numerals :

```
$ echo 10-17-22 | grep -oP '[0-9]{2}'
10
17
22
$
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "10:30:01"|sed "s/:/\n/g"| awk '{print substr($1,1,1)}'
```

```
output
1
3
0
```

```
echo "10-17-22" | awk -F "-" 'OFS="\n"{print $1,$2,$3}'
```

output

```
10
17
22
```